# SMTP client stops with HELO command

Tags: java, sockets, smtp

I have been trying to get this SMTP client up and running. The client reaches the server and is able to send the HELO message. I am also able to get a successful acknowledgement too. But after this first command all the other commands get an acknowledgement saying the command is not recogonised. This is pretty wierd and I am not able to proceed with my program. Please help..:(

Well this is my program..you can just compile it in eclipse and the swing UI l comeup

```
enter code here   
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;

import javax.swing.*;



public class Mail extends javax.swing.JFrame {



    JLabel userLabel = new JLabel("USER");
    JLabel passLabel = new JLabel("PASS");
    JLabel fromLabel = new JLabel("FROM");
    JLabel toLabel = new JLabel("TO");
    JLabel subjectLabel =  new JLabel("SUBJECT");
    JLabel bodyLabel = new JLabel("BODY");
    JLabel serverLabel=new JLabel("SERVER");
    JButton sendButton = new JButton("Send");
    JButton closeButton = new JButton("Close");
    JTextField userText= new JTextField(); 
    JPasswordField passText= new JPasswordField(); 
    JTextField fromText= new JTextField(); 
    JTextField toText= new JTextField(); 
    JTextField subjectText= new JTextField(); 
    JTextField bodyText = new JTextField(); 
    JTextField serverText = new JTextField("smtp.nus.edu.sg");
    JList testList= new JList() ;
    JTextArea test= new JTextArea() ;
    DefaultListModel testArea= new DefaultListModel();
    BufferedReader input ;
    PrintWriter output ; 


    public Mail(){

    setTitle("User Agent");
    this.setSize(1400,1400);
    this.setVisible(true);  
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.getContentPane().setLayout(null);





    userLabel.setBounds(12, 12, 70, 12);
    passLabel.setBounds(12, 48, 70, 12);
    fromLabel.setBounds(12, 84, 70, 12);
    toLabel.setBounds(12, 120, 70, 12);
    subjectLabel.setBounds(12, 156, 70, 12);
    bodyLabel.setBounds(12, 192, 70, 12);
    serverLabel.setBounds(12, 228, 70, 12);
    sendButton.setBounds(12, 264, 70, 22);
    closeButton.setBounds(130, 264, 70, 22);
    //testArea.setBounds(130, 294, 170, 122);

    userText.setBounds(60,12,200,22);
    passText.setBounds(60,48,200,22);
    fromText.setBounds(60,84,200,22);
    toText.setBounds(60,120,200,22);
    subjectText.setBounds(60,156,200,22);
    bodyText.setBounds(60,192,200,22);
    serverText.setBounds(60,228,200,22);    
    testList.setBounds(130, 294, 970, 922); 
    test.setBounds(400, 294, 970, 922); 


    getContentPane().add(userLabel);
    getContentPane().add(passLabel);
    getContentPane().add(fromLabel);
    getContentPane().add(toLabel);
    getContentPane().add(subjectLabel);
    getContentPane().add(bodyLabel);
    getContentPane().add(serverLabel);
    getContentPane().add(sendButton);
    getContentPane().add(closeButton);
    getContentPane().add(userText);
    getContentPane().add(passText);
    getContentPane().add(fromText);
    getContentPane().add(toText);
    getContentPane().add(subjectText);
    getContentPane().add(bodyText);
    getContentPane().add(serverText);
    getContentPane().add(testList);
//      getContentPane().add(test);

    testList.setModel(testArea);
    testArea.addElement("this is a test message");

/*thehandler handler = new thehandler();
sendButton.addActionListener(handler);
*/
    theHandler handler = new theHandler();
    closeButton.addActionListener(handler);
   sendButton.addActionListener(handler);
}
class theHandler implements java.awt.event.ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent event){
    Object happen = event.getSource();
    if (happen == closeButton)
      closeButton_actionPerformed(event);
    else if(happen == sendButton)
        sendButton_actionPerformed(event);


}
}

/*void Send_actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent event) {
System.exit(0);
}*/



void closeButton_actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent event) {
    System.exit(0);
    //testText.setText("vikas");
}

void sendButton_actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent event) {

    try{
    Socket sock = new Socket(serverText.getText(), 25);
    //testArea.addElement(sock);
 output = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream(),true);
 input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));




//output.flush();   

 pass(null);
pass("HELO\r\n");
pass("AUTH LOGIN\r\n");
//pass("AUTH LOGIN\r\n");
//pass(null);



//pass("TlVTU1RVXHUwOTA2OTc1");
//pass("TlVTU1RVXHUwOTA2OTc1");


    }
    catch(Exception e){
    testArea.addElement("Error");   
    }
    }
    //testText.setText("vikas");


void pass(String s)throws java.io.IOException{

    if(s!=null){
        output.println(s);
    System.out.println(s);  


        testArea.addElement("Me");
        testArea.addElement(s);
    }




    String inline = input.readLine();
    if(inline!= null)
        testArea.addElement("Him");
    testArea.addElement(inline);

//  test.setText(inline);

}

public static void main(String args[]) {
 Mail theMail = new Mail();
 theMail.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


}



}
```

Comment: Don't just post your whole program and ask someone to read and fix it. Identify a specific problem and post the minimum code necessary to reproduce it.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are sending `HELO` instead of `EHLO`, the server probably isn't enabling support for the ESMTP command `AUTH`.

Answer (score 0):

The [RFC 5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321) for SMTP requires that HELO should include a FQDN (a hostname with domain), depending on which SMTP Server you are using it might refuse communication because of that. Furthermore HELO is deprecated in favour of EHLO command.

Did you consider using [Java Mail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html) or [Commons-email](http://commons.apache.org/email/) instead of doing all the protocol handling yourself?